# How can I automatically hide an NSScroller in Lion?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion, nsscroller

I have an NSScroller that is used to scroll some complete custom view of mine. With `[scroller setScrollerStyle:[NSScroller preferredScrollerStyle]]` I get the correct style of the scroller. Now when the scroller has `NSScrollerStyleOverlay`, I assumed it will automatically hide when it is not used. Like it does when using a standard NSScrollView. But it doesn't. It's always visible.

Is there a suggested way to hide the scrollers automatically? Or do I have to do that manual with timers etc?

Comment: I had the same problem, and made my own scroll view. https://github.com/hoshi-takanori/MyScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up redesigning my view's so they fit in a UIScrollView. So I worked around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Your scroller and go to "Attributes inspector" and check checkbox "Automatically Hide Scroller". That should do it.

Comment: You're talking about the `NSScrollView`. I'm talking about a `NSScroller` without a `NSScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

See [What's New in Mac OS X 10.7 — Overlay Scrollbars](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_7.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010355-SW39)

Under *Compatibility Notes*, you may be probably hitting the 3rd case: "Any NSScroller that is not managed by an NSScrollView". Or possibly you have an "external pointing device" that doesn't fully support overlay scrollers?